# Does "A Second Chance at Eden" require knowledge of "The Night's Dawn" trilogy or can it be stand-alone?

Tags: suggested-order, nights-dawn-trilogy

I am very familiar with *The Night's Dawn* trilogy but only recently found out about this collection of short stories - one of which was apparently adapted into an episode of "Love, Death & Robots."

My key question is whether this collection works as a stand-alone, as I'm thinking of submitting it to my book club and I'd only want to do that if it'd make sense to people other than me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the stories in the collection were first published *before* the *Night’s Dawn* trilogy, and so of course they don’t require knowledge of the trilogy. If anything, you should read it before reading the trilogy, to get an introduction to the background.